# How to transfer the notes from the tasks in a Project Quote to a Project?

Tags: acumatica

I am attempting to setup a button on the Projects screen of the Project Management module that when pressed will transfer the task notes from the Project Quote that created the Project, to the tasks of the Project.

I'm basing my code off of a very similar situation that I encountered when I created a button that would transfer the header and task notes from a Project Template to a Project Quote that used said Project Template.

Here is the code that I am basing my current project on. This creates a button on the Project Quote screen that when pressed, transfers the notes in the Project Template to the current Project Quote.

```
    public PXAction<PMQuote> ImportNotes;
    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Import Notes From Template")]
    public virtual void importNotes()
    {
        PMQuote row = Base.Quote.Current;
        PXCache cache = Base.Quote.Cache;

        PMProject template = PXSelect<PMProject, Where<PMProject.contractID, Equal<Current<PMQuote.templateID>>>>.Select(Base); 
        ProjectEntry projectEntry = PXGraph.CreateInstance<ProjectEntry>();

        TemplateTaskMaint tempTask = PXGraph.CreateInstance<TemplateTaskMaint>();


        string taskNotes;
        foreach(PMQuoteTask task in Base.Tasks.Select() )
        {

                tempTask.Task.Current = tempTask.Task.Search<PMTask.taskCD>(task.TaskCD);
                if(tempTask.Task.Current != null)
                {
                    taskNotes = PXNoteAttribute.GetNote(tempTask.Task.Cache, tempTask.Task.Current);
                    PXNoteAttribute.SetNote(Base.Tasks.Cache, task, taskNotes);
                    Base.Actions.PressSave();
                }
        }


        string tempNotes = PXNoteAttribute.GetNote(projectEntry.Project.Cache, template);
        PXNoteAttribute.SetNote(cache, row, tempNotes);
        Base.Actions.PressSave();

    }
```

And here is the code I'm having a problem with, where I would like the notes from a Project Quote to be transferred to a Project.

```
public PXAction<PMProject> ImportNotes;
    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Import Notes From Quote")]
    public virtual void importNotes()
    {
        //Create an instance of the PMQuoteMaint to retrieve the PMQuoteTask notes from
        PMQuoteMaint quoteMaint = PXGraph.CreateInstance<PMQuoteMaint>();


        string taskNotes;

        //Loop through all the Tasks in the current Project
        foreach(PMTask task in Base.Tasks.Select())
        {
                //PMQuoteTasks and PMTasks share TaskCDs, here we are finding and assigning the current 
                //PMQuoteTask in the PMQuoteMaint based on the current PMTask's TaskCD in the ProjectEntry
                quoteMaint.Tasks.Current = quoteMaint.Tasks.Search<PMQuoteTask.taskCD>(task.TaskCD);


                //Here we check if the current PMQuoteTask is null, which it will if there isn't a shared Task
                if(quoteMaint.Tasks.Current != null) 
                {
                    //Get the notes from the current PMQuoteTask
                    taskNotes = PXNoteAttribute.GetNote(quoteMaint.Tasks.Cache, quoteMaint.Tasks.Current);
                    //Assign the notes from the current PMQuoteTask to the current PMTask
                    PXNoteAttribute.SetNote(Base.Tasks.Cache, task, taskNotes);
                    //Save Changes
                    Base.Actions.PressSave();
                }
        }
    }
```

The code compiles fine, but when the button is pressed on the Project screen, the tasks notes do not transfer and I am having a difficult time ascertaining what the problem is. I would expect with this code that when the button is pressed the notes in the tasks tab of the associated Project Quote to be transferred to the same tasks in the tasks tab of the Project that was created by the Project Quote.

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed your code as well as the base code in the Repository.

The tasks are bound to the current QuoteID.

```
[PXViewName(Messages.PMTasks)]
[PXImport(typeof(PMQuote))]
[PXCopyPasteHiddenFields(typeof(PMQuoteTask.plannedStartDate), typeof(PMQuoteTask.plannedEndDate))]
public PXSelect<PMQuoteTask, Where<PMQuoteTask.quoteID, Equal<Current<PMQuote.quoteID>>>> Tasks;
```

Because of this, you should first select the quote, and then select the task.

```
quoteMaint.Quote.Current = quoteMaint.Quote.Search<PMQuote.quoteNbr>(Base.Project.Current.QuoteNbr);
quoteMaint.Tasks.Current = quoteMaint.Tasks.Search<PMQuoteTask.taskCD>(task.TaskCD);
```

I have tested this by going to a quote with a linked project, adding a note, and then running through your function.